# Is there a way to NOT share gaming statistics with friends on Steam?

Tags: steam

I really like how I can jump into the same game / server as my friend is currently playing on Steam, so I definitely like the "friends" feature.

However, I dislike the fact that steam exposes my entire gaming history to all my friends - for example, the amount of hours I spent with each of my games.

I tried searching but could not find how to prevent it, is there a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Steam has changed since 2010 so here is the updated 2018 answer*

**Yes**, you can hide your personal stats. Per the [blog post](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1667896941884942467) made in April of this year you can hide your "hours played" and manage what you share by logging into your account and following these steps:

> 1. Click the [Your Username] > "Profile" link from the drop down top level navigation.
> 2. Click the "Edit Profile" button
> 3. Click the "My Privacy Settings" link from the side navigation
> 4. Check the box labeled "*Always keep my total playtime private even if users can see my game details.*"

This will hide your stats!

Answer (score 17):

You can make your profile fully private, following [these instructions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4113-YUDH-6401):

> 1. Log into your Steam Community Profile
> 2. Click the Edit my SteamID page link
> 3. Click the  Settings link
> 4. Choose your privacy state
> 5. Click the Save button

However, it hides away all the profile, not only the gaming history.

Comment: But, will it allow my friends to see when I'm online at all, and which game am I correctly playing?

Comment: I believe that this still makes you visible, it just makes your profile private.

Comment: @Oak - this is not linked to profile, but to you being connected to "friends", so yes, like McKay said.

Comment: So can people still friend you if your profile is private?

Comment: @Dronz Friend requests are unaffected by profile privacy status.

Comment: @3ventic So if I make my profile Private, I can hide my 19,000 hours playing Barbie, but still relate to friends by sending them messages, friending, etc?

Comment: @Dronz - yes, this.

Answer (score -4):

Click on "Steam" botton (top left side) Then click "Go Offline" and all of you activity on a game will be hidden , but it only works for Offline games (single player) Or games that don't use steam servers .

Comment: How will this prevent steam from telling his friends the hours in game?