# Is it possible to clear OR hide Steam's Hours Played stat?

Tags: steam

Is it really impossible to not have Steam track your time playing multi-player games?

This seems like an obvious privacy issue to me, no? Is it at least possible to not share them? Also, is there a way to not have them displayed as you log in and look at your own profile?

Is there no way to let people use the other Steam friend features, but not have your playing hours be shown to them?

Comment: I guess you can contact [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/), they may agree to reset the stats.

Comment: Seems to me this is NOT a duplicate of the "disable" question, as I am also asking about clearing the record, or of options to not share it at all. If anything, it's closer to this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/959/is-there-a-way-to-not-share-gaming-statistics-with-friends-on-steam?rq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, no. There is no built in-option to hide your hours played. The only way to achieve this is to set your profile on private, but then no one will be able to access the profile.

If you don't want anybody to know that you played over 1000 hours Barbie and friends, create an extra steam-account and buy the game there. ;)

Comment: You can also try launching the game outside of Steam. Not all games distributed on Steam require it.

Comment: Man Barbie and Friends is my favorite game but all my friends make fun of me for it!  I will have to try that XD

Comment: I know there's a trick to change the system time to the future while the game is running. Steam compares the timestamp for start and end, and deduces playtime from that. Maybe if you set it to the past, it adds a negative number? You'd at least be able to reset your playtime then :)

Comment: You can also start in offline mode. Steam won't track the play time

Comment: Wow... This is having me reconsider continuing playing my multiplayer Steam games at all. Thanks.

Comment: Because, actually, I want to entice my friends to play Barbie with me, but I am sure it will freak them out and scare them off if they see the thousands of hours I have played it. But I don't want to lose my accumulated harem of Kens.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to hide hours played, nor is there a way to reset it.

You can however, prevent it from building up. Playing games in offline mode will not count towards your hours. You will not be able to play Steamworks games multiplayer, though (And sometimes not at all).